Flutter: Are there any ways to speed up `canvas.drawPath` for a complex path?
This is the raster performance that I am getting from drawing a path with 200k lines:
https://i.sstatic.net/65uYK9aB.png
I am trying to create a custom graph using using CustomPainter, and find it a bit odd that it would take this long to render 200k lines in Flutter while libraries like Python's Matplotlib could easily handle millions of points.
When going beyond 200k points, the rendering will take even longer (And sometimes up to several minutes).
During this time, the UI becomes unresponsive until the rendering finishes.
The path is being drawn using this code:
canvas.drawPath(
    linePath,
    Paint()
      ..color = Colors.orange
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2,
);

It seems to me from the screenshot that the problem is with the raster thread.
Are there any performance optimizations that can be done with canvas.drawPath to things up? If there is no way to speed it up, are there any alternatives to this?

The performance issue you're experiencing with rendering a large number of lines using canvas.drawPath() in Flutter is not uncommon. Flutter, being a cross-platform framework, has some inherent limitations when it comes to handling extremely complex and resource-intensive graphics operations.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
